# How to adjust image to get round corners with out cropping?

Tags: android

I need to set image as icon in my application, it needs to make image have rounded corners, I don't want to crop image, how can I achieve it? which methods I need to use? Which scaling type I need to use?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 0):

Use the shape background for image

Create a file called bg_back.xml in your drawable directory.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
       <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
       <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" 
                 android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Call this in your ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_back"/>
```